# Asp.Net 4 File System publishing of Web App

Tags: asp.net, iis

Must be doing something stupid but can't see it.
App created from default template using master page Site.Master. 
`'File System'` Published to local folder on Development machine(WinServer 2008 R2, IIS7)
Browse to localhost/MyWebApp/Account/login.aspx OK
After password validation login.aspx attempts to redirect.

> Response.Redirect(@"~/wfMyForm.aspx");

Browser errors with 
    The file `'/MyWebApp/wfMyWebForm.aspx.cs'` does not exist.
I assume the cs file has been compiled into the DLL in the bin directory so why is it attempting to find the Source code file in the Application directory? Have I missed a configuration option or something?

Made a simple test app and get same result. If no code behind file attached to Target page  the redirect occurs OK.
Attach a code behind file and redirect fails 'no such file'.

```
<%@ Page CodeFile="wfTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="PubTest.wfTest" Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Site.Master"  CodeBehind="wfTest.aspx.cs"%>
```

I have tried various application pools no effect.
Thanksfile does not exist

Comment: are you using a "Web Site Project" or a "Web Application Project"? I believe web site projects do not default to precompiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using a "Web Site Project" but you are expecting the default behavior of a "Web Application Project".

A comparison of the two: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28VS.80%29.aspx#wapp_topic5

Options for precompiling a "Web Site Project": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx

Comment: None so blind as those who will not see... There was a codefile attribute plus a codebehind attribute in the page header script of the target page. Bad Hair Day.